# Forcing Horizontal Load

Tags: javascript, css, json, wordpress, orientation

I have a website tyloz.com. The website is set in a way that it shows a message on phone to tilt the screen to view website. But the issue it when the website is loaded on desktop the message still shows the message for 2-3ms. Is there a way totally disable the message from desktop? Any help is appreciated.

This is the CSS code that has been used on the website;

```
#warning-message {
        display: none !important;
    }

    @media only screen and (orientation:portrait) {
        .l-header,.l-main,.l-footer {
            display: none!important;
        }
        #warning-message {
            display: block!important;
            background: #2d232e;
            text-align: center;
        }
        body {
            background: #2D232E;
        }
    }
```

Comment: _“still shows the message for 2-3ms”_ - you mean, before the stylesheet is loaded/parsed/applied? Then you’d have to use inline styles, if you want to prevent *that*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your warning message loads before anything:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html class="" lang="en-US">
<div id="warning-message">
<img src="http://www.tyloz.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/warningmessage.png">
</div>
```

Move it to below your preloader:

```
<div class='l-preloader with_spinner'><div class='l-preloader-spinner'><div class='w-preloader  type_1'><div class='w-preloader-h'></div></div></div></div>
<div id="warning-message">
<img src="http://www.tyloz.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/warningmessage.png">
</div>
<!-- HEADER -->
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you so much. I was loosing my mind because of that.